# How to catch g-recaptcha-response in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, viewmodel, recaptcha

I am trying to post the form with ReCaptcha to a mvc Controller.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="some_site_key"></div>
```

from the network monitor in chrome I can see the data fired off

[image]

however I am struggling with receiving this data in the controller, I tried using a viewmodel `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Captcha required")]
 public string googleCaptcha { get; set; }`

but I can't map the variable *googleCaptcha*  to  *g-recaptcha-response*, is there a data attribute that allows me to do so?

I obviously can't name the variable *g-recaptcha-response* because c# doesn't allow those naming conventions

Answer (score 7):

There are several examples that create a custom Bind attribute that allows you to specify an alias, which is the way I would go if you are aliasing several properties:
https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/bind-a-model-property-to-a-different-named-query-string-field.html

However, for a one-off approach, I would simply read the submitted values and set my property manually:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAction()
{
    var recaptchaResponse = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];

    var myCaptcha = new MyCaptcha();
    myCaptcha.googleCaptcha = recaptchaResponse

    //..
}
```

Comment: Thank you last bit totally did it

Comment: * Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];